# Using SELECT statement with COUNT

Tags: sql

```
CREATE TABLE hardware
(
name        varchar(10),
ID      serial              PRIMARY KEY    NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE games
(
name        varchar(100),
ID      serial                  PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE gameVersion
(
gameID      integer         REFERENCES games(ID),
version     integer,
ID      char(10)        PRIMARY KEY     NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE versionHardware
(
hardwareID      integer         REFERENCES hardware(ID),
versionID       char(10)        REFERENCES gameVersion(ID),
ID      serial          PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE cheatCodes
(
ID      serial          PRIMARY KEY     NOT NULL,
code        varchar(60),
gameID      integer         REFERENCES games(ID)
);
```

How can i find the number of cheatCodes on record for any game that can be played by hardware with ID of (5).

I tried

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM cheatCodes, games, gameVersion,hardware, versionHardware
    WHERE cheatCodes.GameId = games.ID
    AND   gameVersion.gameID = games.ID
    AND   versionHardware.versionID = gameVersion.ID
    AND   hardware.ID = 5;
```

But it doesn't give me the correct answer.

Comment: Are you missing group by?

Comment: i don't think group by will help me, because i'm looking for the number of games. Am i right?

Comment: You are missing JOIN condition for hardware.

Comment: I've never heard of JOIN before, would you please tell how to use it

Comment: @user2821471 I see the query you've posted with your question is copied from previous answer on same question asked by you, if you don't know JOINs in SQL please i request you to learn basics so you will solve your problem on your own.

Comment: Hardware table is not related to any other table in your query, it will not show up.

Comment: I have already seen your comments about JOINs, but the problem that JOINs weren't cover in our lectures, so i'm trying to find another way to solve the problem without using JOINs.

Comment: @Edper, Hardware is related to each version, because each game has couple versions and each version can be played by one or more Hardware(s)

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT cheatCodes.GameId) as CheatCodeCount
FROM cheatCodes, games, gameVersion,hardware, versionHardware
WHERE cheatCodes.GameId = games.ID
AND   gameVersion.gameID = games.ID
AND   versionHardware.versionID = gameVersion.ID
AND   versionHardware.hardwareID = hardware.id 
AND   hardware.ID = 5;
```

Comment: Man, you saved my life. I was stock in this statement for the whole day. God bless you all

Comment: Glad to be of help @user2821471. Happy coding and GOD bless.

Answer (score 0):

please try with the below query.
link for hardware table was missing.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM cheatCodes, games, gameVersion,hardware, versionHardware
    WHERE cheatCodes.GameId = games.ID
    AND   gameVersion.gameID = games.ID
    AND   versionHardware.versionID = gameVersion.ID
    AND   hardware.id = versionHardware.hardwareID      
    AND   hardware.ID = 5;
```

Comment: The correct result is 2, but my SELECT gave me 38 where 37 of them are duplicates values and i used DISTINCT but it doesn't help. Your SELECT gave me somehow a result of 7

Comment: i only added the hardware.id = versionHardware.hardwareID  in your query. mayb you can post the data in the different tables.